# TypeScript Return Type: void

Tags: angular, typescript

In TypeScript (using in an Angular project), for a method that returns nothing (void), which of the following is the best practice?

```
onSelect(someNumber: number): void {

}
```

OR

```
onSelect(someNumber: number) {

}
```

I've seen it both ways in different examples and wasn't sure if it is better to add the return type as void or to leave it blank?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's entirely personal preference whether you explicitly annotate a method's return type or not, especially for a trivial type like `void`.

Reasons you might add `: void`:

- Improves clarity - other devs don't have to read the method body to see if it returns anything
- Safer - if you e.g. move code from another function into this one that has a `return expr;` statement in it, TypeScript will flag this mistake

Reasons you might not:

- Brevity - if it's clear from context what the return type should be (e.g. `getLength()` is almost certainly returning `number`), then a return type annotation is slightly noisy
- Flexibility - if you're prototyping this code and aren't sure yet what you want the return type to be, leaving it inferred lets you change it more easily

Comment: Another reason to add `:void`: Static analysis tools can more easily determine the function's output, flagging errors and potential errors in usage of those functions. (Note: ReSharper/VS sometimes provide better feedback in large code bases if lower level functions specify their output types, reducing the load on the tools.)

Comment: Isn't it "entirely personal preference" whether you annotate _anything_?
Isn't best practice _more_ annotation?
[This eslint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) certainly thinks so.

Answer (score 5):

Remember the Rule : "void is the return type of a function/method that doesn’t explicitly return anything"

Whether your use "void" or not as return type in function/method, its automatically infer to "void" return type if there is no explicit return type

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is when you are using strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Another use-case which benefits from being explicit with 'void' return type IMO is one-line arrow functions.

```
// the second method has no body block, and implicitly returns the 
// size of the internal array, which may not be the desired outcome
// explicitly stating a :void return type would flag the bottom one
// as an error
add = (v: string):  => {this.list.push(v);};
addAndReturnLengthOfList = (v: string):  => this.list.push(v);

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be to return nothing or undefined:

```
return undefined;
```

Especially on case when you are using comma:

```
handleError = (key, data = {}) => (this.template(key, data), undefined);
```